# Performance SQLAlchemy and or

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I use the following sqlalchemy code to retrieve some data from a database

```
q = session.query(hd_tbl).\
    join(dt_tbl, hd_tbl.c['data_type'] == dt_tbl.c['ID']).\
    filter(or_(and_(hd_tbl.c['object_id'] == get_id(row['object']),
                    hd_tbl.c['data_type'] == get_id(row['type']),
                    hd_tbl.c['data_provider'] == get_id(row['provider']),
                    hd_tbl.c['data_account'] == get_id(row['account']))
           for index, row in data.iterrows())).\
    with_entities(hd_tbl.c['ID'], hd_tbl.c['object_id'],
                  hd_tbl.c['data_type'], hd_tbl.c['data_provider'],
                  hd_tbl.c['data_account'], dt_tbl.c['value_type'])
```

where `hd_tbl`and `dt_tbl` are two tables in sql db, and `data`is pandas dataframe containing typically around 1k-9k entries. `hd_tbl` contains at the moment around 90k rows.

The execution time seems to exponentially grow with the length of `data`. The corresponding sql statement (by sqlalchemy) looks as follows:

```
SELECT data_header.`ID`, data_header.object_id, data_header.data_type, data_header.data_provider, data_header.data_account, basedata_data_type.value_type 
FROM data_header INNER JOIN basedata_data_type ON data_header.data_type = basedata_data_type.`ID` 
WHERE data_header.object_id = %s AND data_header.data_type = %s AND data_header.data_provider = %s AND data_header.data_account = %s OR 
data_header.object_id = %s AND data_header.data_type = %s AND data_header.data_provider = %s AND data_header.data_account = %s OR
 ...
 data_header.object_id = %s AND data_header.data_type = %s AND data_header.data_provider = %s AND data_header.data_account = %s OR
```

The tables and columns are fully indexed, and performance is not satisfying. Currently it is way faster to read all the data of `hd_tbl` and `dt_tbl` into memory and merge with pandas merge function. However, this is seems to be suboptimal. Anyone having an idea on how to improve the sqlalchemy call?

EDIT:
I was able to improve performance signifcantly by using sqlalchemy tuple_ in the following way:

```
header_tuples = [tuple([int(y) for y in tuple(x)]) for x in
                 data_as_int.values]
q = session.query(hd_tbl). \
    join(dt_tbl, hd_tbl.c['data_type'] == dt_tbl.c['ID']). \
    filter(tuple_(hd_tbl.c['object_id'], hd_tbl.c['data_type'],
                  hd_tbl.c['data_provider'],
                  hd_tbl.c['data_account']).in_(header_tuples)). \
    with_entities(hd_tbl.c['ID'], hd_tbl.c['object_id'],
                  hd_tbl.c['data_type'], hd_tbl.c['data_provider'],
                  hd_tbl.c['data_account'], dt_tbl.c['value_type'])
```

with corresponding query...

```
SELECT data_header.`ID`, data_header.object_id, data_header.data_type, data_header.data_provider, data_header.data_account, basedata_data_type.value_type 
FROM data_header INNER JOIN basedata_data_type ON data_header.data_type = basedata_data_type.`ID` 
WHERE (data_header.object_id, data_header.data_type, data_header.data_provider, data_header.data_account) IN ((%(param_1)s, %(param_2)s, %(param_3)s, %(param_4)s), (%(param_5)s, ...))
```

Comment: Well of course it's going to be slow; you're doing a `JOIN` by looping over one of the tables and constructing a huge `WHERE` clause with thousands of conditions. You need to create a temp table from your dataframe and do a proper `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you create a composite index on fields `object_id`, `data_type`, `data_provider`, `...` with the same order, which they are placed in table, and make sure they're following in the same order in your WHERE condition. It may speed-up a bit your requests by cost of the disk space.

Also you may use several consequent small SQL requests instead a large query with complex `OR` condition. Accumulate extracted data on the application side or, if amount is large enough, in a fast temporary storage (a temporary table, noSQL, etc.)

In addition you may check MySQL configuration and increase values, related to memory volume per a thread, request, etc. A good idea is to check is your composite index fits into available memory, or it is useless.

I guess DB tuning may help a lot to increase productivity. Otherwise you may analyze your application's architecture to get more significant results.